# Arrow function is undefined in extended calass

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, express

I have a class, and another class that extends the fist one.
In my code I create a new instance of the extended class: `new MyCustomEndpoint(router);`

the problem is that `handleIsNotOk` is `undefined` in `initMyRoutes`

```js
export class MyEndpoint {
    constructor(router: express.Router) {
        this.initMyRoutes(router); 
    }

    protected initMyRoutes(router: express.Router) {
        router.get(`/v1/isok`, this.handleIsOk);
    }

    protected handleIsOk = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        res.send(200);
    }
}


export class MyCustomEndpoint extends MyEndpoint{
    private test = "Test";

    protected initMyRoutes(router: express.Router) {
        console.log(this.handleIsNotOk); // undefined
        console.log(this.handleIsNotOkFn);

        router.get(`/v1/isokcustom`, this.handleOk); // this works
        router.get(`/v1/isnotok`,this.handleIsNotOk); // this doesn't works
        router.get(`/v1/isnotokfn`, this.handleIsNotOkFn); // this doesn't works
        router.get(`/v1/isnotokfn`, (req, res)this.handleIsNotOkFn(req,res)); // works but it's ugly since it's different compared to router.get(`/v1/isokcustom`, this.handleOk);
    }

    protected handleIsNotOk = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        res.send(200);
    }

    protected handleIsNotOkFn(req: express.Request, res: express.Response){
        console.log(this.test); // undefined
        res.send(200);
    }
}

...

new MyCustomEndpoint(router);
```

why is this happening? should not be `undefined` in my opinion

Comment: Most likely: [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484) I suspect `initMyRoutes` is passed as a method reference (e.g. `somethingThatTakesCallback(this.initMyRoutes)`), which will always lose the value of `this` when it gets executed.

Comment: yes, but what would be your suggested solution? I know I can do it like this: `router.get(`/v1/isnotokfn`, this._chatPermissionSecurity.readAccessMiddleware, (req,res) => this.handleIsNotOkFn(req,res));` but I don't like it since it's a different approach than in `MyEndpoint`

Comment: `protected function handleIsNotOkFn() {...}` is not a syntactically valid class member

Comment: @AluanHaddad why not? as described in my comment above, it actually works (but I don't like it)

Comment: Sorry but it's not. What do you think it means?

Comment: @AluanHaddad yeah it should be `protected handleIsNotOkFn(req: express.Request, res: express.Response){}` (copy paste error). But would be nice if you help to find an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Self Answer

Thanks to @mbojko @Keith @VLAZ and everyone else for the answers.

Even if technically correct, the solutions didn't fit my needs.
My use-case is kinda peculiar and there is a reason why I am doing it like this.

FYI:
This is the solution that fits my needs

```js
export class MyCustomEndpoint extends MyEndpoint{

    constructor(router: express.Router) {
        super(router);
        this.initCustomRoutes(router);
    }

    // will be called in the constructor of the super class
    protected initMyRoutes(router: express.Router) {
        router.get(`/v1/isokcustom`, this.handleOk); 
    }

    private initCustomRoutes(router: express.Router) {
        router.get(`/v1/isokcustom`, this.handleOkCustom); 
    }

    protected handleOkCustom = (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
        res.send(200);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I bet *this* is the reason

```
router.get(`/v1/isnotokfn`, this.handleIsNotOkFn);
```

and if you bind it to the instance, it'll work just fine:

```
router.get(`/v1/isnotokfn`, this.handleIsNotOkFn.bind(this));
```

Comment: thanks, this works, same as `(req,res) => this.handleIsNotOkFn(req,res));`

but it's kinda of ugly since it's not the same syntax as in `MyEndpoint` but probably the only solution

Comment: @Zerotwelve  An arrow function will loose any concept of a class, so yes, you will need to use bind.  Or avoid class altogether and just use functional coding, personally I find that less ugly..

Comment: @Keith the arrow function in `MyEndpoint` `handleIsOk` works fine and I have reference on `this`, the same exact code in `MyCustomEndpoint` doesn't work probably because `this` references  the super Class

Comment: @Zerotwelve  Have you come on SO for help, or just constantly contradict everything people say.  If so, you will find nobody will want to help you.   An arrow function has no concept of a class, it has no `this`.  Your `handleIsOk` works now, only because there is no reference to the class, soon as you want that your up the creek without a paddle.

Comment: @Keith I am not trying to contradict everyone, actually I upvoted this answer. I am looking for a suitable solution to my use case

Comment: Actually, arrow functions _don't_ lose the context, they use lexical `this`. It's the `function` functions that don't behave and require putting more thought into the "what is _this_?" question. Inheritance complicates things even more.

Comment: @mbojko  Yes, wording slightly wrong, but I was on about were the OP was attaching an arrow function to a class,  `this` will be `undefined`..  As the context then will be nothing..

Comment: @Zerotwelve  If you want to avoid bind, ironically an arrow function is what this was designed for, but you need to be using it at the caller end, not the class.  eg.  `router.get('/v1/isnotokfn', () =>  this.handleIsNotOkFn());`,   Is this less ugly than bind, that's something only you can decide.

Answer (score 0):

You overwrite `initMyRoutes` and you're waiting your mother class to call the new `initMyRoutes`. You should have a constructor in `MyCustomEndPoint` where you call `initMyRoutes`. **`MyCustomEndPoint` never calls `initMyRoutes`**

Comment: no, MyCustomEndpoint inherits the constructor from "MyEndpoint".
 `initMyRoutes` gets called (i see the logs)

Comment: yes but not the right one, it calls initMyRoutes which is declared in MyEndpoint